# Install unity3d 2017version in ubuntu

Tags: unity3d

I am new in linux. I saw some tutorial but that is old there is no tutorial for the new versions.plzzz help me to install the latest version of unity3d in Ubuntu.

Here's the link :--
  https://beta.unity3d.com/download/0ec691fce5c2/public_download.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the latest version reviewed on 5 April 2018 and it does include some error fixes for Unity3D running on Linux. 
https://beta.unity3d.com/download/77a142ac9989/public_download.html

---

Edit!: there was possible to install it using the using umake from terminal, but retesting it today seems to give errors for a lot of applications possible to be installed from umake.

Comment: You might give a try for Godot3 game engine. It is Open Source, able to deliver the same quality of games as Unity3D does and a little better also.  https://godotengine.org/